# Show that if the incircle touches BC at t and TS || to AI s.t S is on the incircle and B'C' tangent to incircle on S, Prove that AB'C' ~ ABC

Tags: geometry

$ \Delta$ ABC has incenter I, its incircle touches the side BC at T. The line through T parallel
to IA meets the incircle again at S and the tangent to the incircle at S meets AB and AC at the
points C' and B' respectively. Prove that $ \Delta$ AB'C' is similar to the $ \Delta$ ABC.

[image: figure]

What I've figued out till now is that it is sufficient to show $C'B' || BC$. And also I've made a cirucumcircle as a construction hoping that it will be handy sometime later.

Please help me out with this.
Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to prove $C'B'\parallel BC$, because it is not always true.

Comment: @ACB thanks. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the figure below.

[image]

Here $BC$ is clearly not parallel to $C'B'$. So you can't prove that.

**Hint**:

Let extended $AI$ meet $BC$ at $F$ and $B'C'$ intersect $AI$ at $G$. 
$\angle TSB'=\angle AGC'=\theta \ (\because AI\parallel ST)$
$\angle ITS=\angle IST=90-\theta$
$\angle STC=\angle AFC=\theta$ 
And $AI$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$.

Can you proceed? (We can easily prove $\angle C=\angle C'$, which I have already done : ) )

Comment: Than you very much!

Comment: could you please tell me where did you make in figure?

Comment: @user868051 , [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks...........